# PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER inside C++ member function cannot compile?

Tags: c++, pthreads

```
class A {
    public:
        A();
    private:
        pthread_mutex_t mu;
};

A::A()
{
    mu = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;  //cannot compile
}
```

Can't I initialize `pthread_mutex_t` inside a class member function?

Comment: What you show is an assignment not an initialization.

Answer (score 12):

Instead of this:

```
A::A()
{
    mu = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;  //cannot compile
}
```

Try this:

```
A::A()
{
pthread_mutex_init( &(mu), NULL);
}
```

The PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER is a macro,a C struct initializer for something like {0,0,0,0,0{0}} and can only be used at the point of definition.

Answer (score 8):

Use [`pthread_mutex_init`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_mutex_init.html) in this case, as the constant is for compile-time initialization.

Comment: Then I cannot put `pthread_mutex_t` data member in the initializtion list, can I?

Comment: Sorry, I meant compile-time initialization, not static initialization. And yes, you cannot put it either (at least if not in C++11) in initialization lists.

Answer (score 2):

Even if we change this to use an initializer list in the constructor it still fails:

```
#include <pthread.h>

struct foo {
  pthread_mutex_t test;
  foo() : test(PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER) {}
};

int main() {
  foo f;
}
```

We can see *why* it fails and an only be used for initialisation in a few contexts by looking at the output from the pre-processsor:

```
struct foo {
  pthread_mutex_t test;
  foo() : test({ { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, { 0 } } }) {}
};
```

It's not legal to use nested braces for initialisation like that in C++03, but what's more interesting perhaps is that C++11 makes this syntax and usage perfectly legal.

In your original code we can see a few more things:

```
A::A()
{
    const pthread_mutex_t test = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER; //  initialization - fine
    mu = test; // assignment - fine
    mu = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;  // assignment - C++11 only
}
```

Comment: The original code is legal C++11 also, probably you don't have C++11 support enabled in your compiler.

Comment: @Alcott there are only 3 major versions of the standard - don't mix compiler versions from a specific vendor with standard versions.

Answer (score 0):

I like the answers from @askmish & @Diego. I like also what @Flexo explained.

But just as an option, if you are intent on initializing with the `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` macro, what you can do is, make the mutex declaration inside the class definition `static` like this:

```
class A {
    public:
        A();
    private:
        static pthread_mutex_t mu;
};
```

And then you can initialize this static mutex in your source file BUT outside any member function, like this:

```
class A {
    public:
        A();
    private:
        static pthread_mutex_t mu;
};

pthread_mutex_t A::mu = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

A::A()
{
}
```

**Your options:**

- So either you keep the macro and go static (as shown here). OR,
- you keep the declaration of the mutex the same (non-static) but use the `pthread_mutex_init()` function (as others have indicated) inside your member-function.