# taking an error in a simple producer consumer example when initialize a mutex

Tags: c, pthreads, posix, mutex, semaphore

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER inside C++ member function cannot compile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11666718/pthread-mutex-initializer-inside-c-member-function-cannot-compile)

I'm trying to implement a producer/consumer problem with POSIX threads and semaphores but I'm facing the following error:

```
sema.c: In function ‘initialize_variables’:
sema.c:55:8: error: expected expression before ‘{’ token
```

I've checked my code but couldn't see where to attribute this error.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 10
#define TRUE 1

pthread_mutex_t mutex;

sem_t full, empty;

int buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

int counter;

void* producer(void*);
void* consumer(void*);

int insert_item(void);
int remove_item(void);

void initialize_variables();

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int number_Pro;
    int number_Cons;
    int i;

    if(argc!=3){
        printf("Not enough parameters\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    number_Pro = atoi(argv[1]);
    number_Cons = atoi(argv[2]);

    pthread_t t_array_Pro[number_Pro];
    pthread_t t_array_Cons[number_Cons];

    initialize_variables();

    for(i=0; i<number_Pro; i++)
        pthread_create(&t_array_Pro[i],NULL,producer,NULL);

    for(i=0; i<number_Cons; i++)
        pthread_create(&t_array_Cons[i],NULL,consumer,NULL);

    return 0;
}

void initialize_variables(){

    mutex=PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

    sem_init(&full,0,0);
    sem_init(&empty,0,BUFFER_SIZE);

    counter = 0;
}

void* producer(void* arg){

    while(TRUE){

        sem_wait(&empty);

        phtread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

            if(insert_item())
                printf("Error in Producer\n");

            else
                printf("Producer produced a new item\n");

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

        sem_post(&full);
    }
}

void* consumer(void* arg){

    while(TRUE){

        sem_wait(&full);

        phtread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

            if(remove_item())
                printf("Error in Consumer\n");

            else
                printf("Consumer consumed an item from the buffer\n");

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

        sem_post(&empty);
    }
}

int insert_item(void){

    if(counter < BUFFER_SIZE){

        buffer[counter]=1;
        counter++;
        return 0;
    }

    else
        return -1;
}

int remove_item(void){

    if(counter > 0){

        buffer[counter]=0;
        counter--;
        return 0;
    }

    else
        return -1;
}
```

Comment: Can you check the code that you have entered here. There are typos in the code that produce different compiler error than you report.    phtread_mutex_lock(&mutex); should be    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex); for example.

Comment: Please capitalize your sentences in accordance with common English.  Whatever your opinion on the matter, that is the custom here.

Comment: @pilcrow: You can and are encouraged to edit posts to help them conform to our QA format.

Comment: @RobKielty upss i didn't see that and thanks for your reply

Comment: @quartaela No worries :-) Looks like you got a good answer, that's the most important thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER macro must be evaluated and the assignment made in a compile-time context. Initialize your mutex at its definition point, or use `pthread_mutex_init`.

In particular, the line:

```
mutex=PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

is parsed as an *assignment expression*, which expects certain kinds of expressions on the right side of it (you can go through the C grammar, it's actually quite simple to understand). The `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` macro typically expands to `{ initializer-list }` [1]. The C grammar specifies that a parenthesized type name must be present before such an initializer list for our initial statement to be valid.

Of course, you can get around that by using a cast expression, but that results in invalid `pthread_mutex_t` object(s) state (if I'm reading the POSIX standard correctly, it results in undefined behaviour).

[1] ..such as `{ { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, { 0, 0 } } }` on my system.

Comment: yeah it can be compiled successfully without having any errors with using pthread_mutex_init. by the way can you explain briefly more that why my way doesnt work properly _?