# extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11

Tags: c++, c++11

I get this error, porting code from C to C++:

> **src/common/atom.cpp:19:8: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11**

```
void Atom::Run(ThreadFunction threadFunction)
{
    mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
    if(threadFunction!=NULL)
    {
        pthread_create(&threadID, NULL, threadFunction, this);
        this->running=true;
    }
}
```

Why do I need this flag in C++ but not in C, and what are initializers?

Comment: Whats the question?

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Do you add the -std=c++11 flag as suggested ?

Comment: Your exact command line?

Comment: oh?? ok but does that flag extends the compiler possibilities or something? I never really understood these kind of options

Comment: Do you have an issue with using c++11? Do you want to know what extended initializer lists are and how they differ from c++03 initializer lists? Do you want to know the *difference* between the two suggested flags? Please, give us a question to answer. We're not psychic.

Comment: yes, with the flag it works, I thought it was a bit weird to need this

Comment: sorry if my problem is a bit vague, but yes what are these flags and why are they required to do so ... and whhat are extended initializers, sorry I come from java world :-)

Comment: @fdsfdsfdsfds by default it compiles with c++03. You need the flag to make it compile using c++11 rules. There's also c++14 and c++1z (soon to be c++17) flags.

Comment: Related, if not a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11666718/10077

Comment: No need to switch language standard over whole project for one syntax quirk. `const pthread_mutex_t mutex_dummy = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER; mutex = mutex_dummy;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Problem

> ```
> src/common/atom.cpp:19:8: warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
> ```

### Solution

As you can see in the error, it tells you to have the flags:

> `std=c++11` or `-std=gnu++11`

This is so you have version C++11. [**Initalizer lists**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) require C++11 .

With the version of C++11, you have many additional features like Lambda Expressions, Automatic Type Deduction and decltype, Uniform Initialization Syntax, Deleted and Defaulted Functions, nullptr, Rvalue References, New Smart Pointer Classes (`shared_ptr`, `unique_ptr`), C++11 Standard Library, More C++ Algorithms, and much more!

### References

[**C++11 FAQ - Bjarne Stroustrup**](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html)

Comment: oh ok, initializers relate to class members initialisation, stupid of me, just that the MUTEX tread macro was not clear and geany is not a great ide to find the declaration of macros, sometimes it works, sometimes it does not

Comment: I'll know from now I have to engage that option for more features, thanks

Comment: @fdsfdsfdsfds this is not the end. There are also many versions such as C++14 , and the new C++17!